Prince Rupert's Drop Armor: How Expensive?
I recently saw this short which showed that, if you melted the tail off of a Prince Rupert's Drop, the head would retain its characteristic toughness without the vulnerability of the tail. This got my worldbuilding mind thinking.

Say a king of a fictional land with the tech of a European nation 1200-1600* wanted a piece of armor the same shape and size as the one pictured above. However, because he wants a really showy and cool-looking piece of armor, he wants the scales to be replaced with Prince Rupert's Drops**. How expensive would this piece of armor theoretically be?***
*You can use any date within that time frame to base your answer upon.
**Not 1 to 1, but enough drops so the piece of armor is covered in drops. They do not have to be dense enough to stop blows, as this will be a ceremonial piece, but they should be densely packed enough to make it look solid. The shoulder pads will not be made of Prince Rupert's Drops. Also, assume that they know what Prince Rupert's Drops are, and that they know that melting the tail off one removes its vulnerability.
***I understand that any prices for pre-modern goods are probably hard to estimate, but the answer should provide a good idea of its cost to manufacture.

You have an incredibly broad range of dates and manufacturing technologies. What is the actual tech level in the world you are building?

@sphennings The question's fine, but answers will only be as good as the input.  The OP could indeed get better answers by providing more and better details.

If what you're looking is for (to coin a phrase, haha) the dollar value of such a suit of armor, you will be required to specify an exact year and location (e.g., a city) so we can use comparative construction and artistic costs to estimate value. If all you were looking for is an explanation of why it might be expensive, @MontyWild's answer is excellent. The devil is in the details on this Stack. You need to be specific about your goals and expectations.

In a pre-modern economy, topics such as expense or cost to manufacture are not really applicable when it comes to expensive artisanal products. All you essentially need to do is pay the artisans enough to live comfortably and supply them with materials (cheap in this case) and that's it. Since you are effectively the only customer (you can casually outbid peasants who need new glass vases or whatever), you can decide on the price.

@Dragongeek has a really good point. During the medieval era, patronage was the most common method of securing "expensive" works of art. The idea of "cost" today is a bit different because ayone who can afford the (somewhat) fixed price can obtain the artifact. Patronage was about providing living expenses and materials and not really "cost," often leading to unique works of art.

The real problem here is: How are the drops going to be attached to the armor, and how will they STAY attached during combat?  Metal circles link through each other to form chain mail with not attachments/weak points.  Scales are specifically shaped so that they are attached at the base and then overlaid by higher scales so that the attachment is protected.  Drops just don't have they right shape to be overlaid this, nor is Rupert-hardened glass workable so that you could make holes or hooks for attachment.

Have you ever heard of a Bologna vial.  Essentially a blown glass variation of the PRD, the BV is a glass bubble which will shatter if scratched on the inside, but hard enough to pound nails on the outside.

I suspect that lead crystal glass would look much flashier and avoid the no-heirs possibilty of exploding Prince Rupert's Drops.

Prince Rupert's Drops are an early form of toughened or tempered glass.
Making toughened glass scale armour might involve making the scales from glass and quenching them in water, before re-melting any thin vulnerable points and piercing the glass for attachment to an underlay.  However, the re-melted parts would still be vulnerable to fracture, just not as vulnerable as the tail of a Prince Rupert's Drop.  Damaging these vulnerable points would likely not result in the complete disintegration of the scale.
Alternatively, after some experimentation, scales could be formed from glass in their final shape and tempered.  Without a thin tail, they wouldn't have points of particular vulnerability.
The material cost of tempered glass scale armour wouldn't be particularly high, probably no more than the cost of a suit of steel scale... until we consider the expertise of the craftsfolk making it.  This would be an extremely niche application of glassworking, and the crafters would charge a large premium... ten times that of a blacksmith's time to a hundred times or more... whatever the market (i.e. the King) would bear.
This isn't a suit of armour, this is a work of art, and art always goes at a premium.  All the more so if it's functionally useful.

This answer could be improved with some kind of reference to an actual period price for a baseline suit of steel scale armor.  (Though it's already good enough that I upvoted.)

@Jedediah Since the time period is so large (1200-1600), the price could vary widely, so I used a relative expense that leaves it up to the OP to do their homework for the exact time period.

I do not think you can pierce a Prince Rupert's Drop without making it implode. You can still attach it in a kind of cage of threads, possibly metal threads. Good enough for ceremony I guess, but probably too far off populace expectations.

Making tempered glass scales would be very hard; medieval technique was not very precise and you'd get a bunch of roughly-the-intended-shape scale, and you can't postprocess the scales into shape by filing. The sequence of casting a scale, tempering it (but without making that process so uneven that the scale will shatter), with preformed holes so that they can be sewn to the base - that's intimidating. Maybe, just maybe, doable by a particularly skilled craftsman - which would fit nicely into a king's ceremonial armor though!

The way I understand it, the question has nothing to do with armor, but rather it is about a fancy coat covered with moderately shiny pieces of some base¹ material.
¹) "Base" material as opposed to precious material.
First, Rupert's drops are a terrible choice. They are not very shiny, and the wearer would need to explain why his glass pebbles are expensive. Having to explain why your odd-looking car is a supercar greatly dimishes its magnetism.
Second, the normal choice would have been sequins. I mean cheap disks of shiny metal (or glass, if you must), not the gold coins of Venice. Besides being shinier, the sequins have the advantage that their shape allows them to be sewn on the fabric or leather substrate.
The scales of scale armor, such as the armor shown in the picture, were held in place by rivets. (Look closely at the picture.) Tiny glass pebbles cannot be rivetted, and can hardly be sewn into place; you would need some sort of glue. Glue and expensive fancy coats don't mix.
Second, the instantly magnetic way of making scale armor crying I am so rich was to have the scales gilt or silvered, or some gilt and some silvered. This has the advantage that the armor remains functional armor, and yet any girl in the vicinity would be instantly impressed by the wealth of the wearer.

Frame challenges 1st:

... a fictional land with the tech of a European nation 1200-1600...
... assume that they know what Prince Rupert's Drops are, and that they know that melting the tail off one removes its vulnerability.

Sorry but you can't just melt the tail off using this level of technology. The linked video used a modern oxyacetylene torch to melt the tip off of a borosilicate glass drop.  It worked because he was able to heat the tip without heating the head and used a kind of glass that did not exist until the late 1800s.  There was no technology in the 1600s that could deliver that much head to such a small point and even if you could, any historical glass would have shattered from heat stress.   The best they could have done is heat the entire bead up to melt the tail off which would have ruined the tempor in the glass.  This means that even if they believe this would work in theory, they could not actually do it with the tools and materials available to them.  So any armor they make will have to include the tails.
Secondly, the picture of scale armor you used as an example is anachronistic, that type of scale armor fell out of use nearly 2000 years before your setting, and no medieval king would consider using it.  The closest they might use would be a lamellar armor which is similar to scale armor except that it is laced or riveted at both the top and bottom.  This was to prevent a blade from simply sliding up between the scales.
Thirdly, if your goal is an obscenely expensive suit of armor made from glass like beads, I'd suggest rubies or sapphires instead.  They are tougher than tempered glass and come without the problematic tails.
How to make it
Prince Rupert's Drops are as delicate as they are tough.  Not only is the tail a major point of vulnerability, but it is also inseparable from a PRD given your tech level. If the tail breaks off, the whole bead breaks, and if you hang a drop by its tail, it will break too easily to be an effective armor which means you need to armor the tail with a secondary material.
To do this you need to forge a scale with a socket, fittings, and perforations in it.

Ultimately, this armor will be kind of lame because the fittings and sockets will take up so much space that the beads themselves will be really hard to make a contiguous pattern out of, and even if you could, they would make the armor to thick and heavy to be all that practical.
As for how much it will cost
The materials themselves would technically be expensive, but nothing compared to the labor of making all these scales with jewelry precision fittings.  The needed  steel itself would probably be no more than 10-20 shillings.  Since this is ceremonial armor, the material cost could be much higher if using high purity silver or gold scale fittings making a price of 1500-36000 shillings very much possible.  The drops are harder to find exact prices for, but we know that a skilled glass maker can make quite a number of them in a day, and would have probably been paid 3-4 shillings a day to make them; so, I would assume these would not exceed 40 shillings, but a bulk order of them for something like this might be quite less.
The other cost here will be the insane amount of labor it will take to forge scales that can hold and protect the beads. The complexity of each scale will be very similar to that of making a custom ring with a stone setting which takes the average jeweler about 25-40 hours of work to make. The average suit of lamellar had 250-300 scales meaning that that suit will require 6250 to 12000 hours of skilled labor.  These scales would require a master blacksmith or jeweler who would make about 4-15 shillings a day meaning that your labor will run about 3125-22500 shillings
This gives you a total possible price range of about \$375,000-\$7,000,000 in modern currency with almost none of the actual cost coming from the glass beads.

As I stated in my question, this suit of armor will be ceremonial, and so doesn’t have to be made to stop blows.

@RHF it is unlike to survive being picked up if you try to string it by the tails.  If this is just meant to be ceremonial, it makes a lot more since to simply make it out of untempered glass beads.  That will make it less fragile overall because you eliminate the weak point, and give you a lot more options for design motifs.

If you want PRDs, and ceremonial, just replace the steel scales with ornate silver or gold scales, but either way you will want these things inset, not hung or drilled into.

It's worth knowing that some folks have shown videos where they melt the tails of PRDs using a blowtorch, and the result is essentially a very, very strong bead without the classic "Achilles Tail".

@ConnieMnemonic Ah, I missed that part.  By definition, if you do that, they are no longer a  Prince Rupert's Drop, just a tempered glass.  Also, you can't do that without a modern blowtorch.  Using medieval heating methods, you'd ruin the temper of the glass.

I think they can do it; use a piece of orange hot iron to melt the tail off.

@Joshua You can't melt a solid material just by touching it with another solid material equal to its melting temperature.  It has to be much hotter to create enough heat transfer before it cools down, and you generally won't have enough contact surface with solid iron to melt the tip before enough heat can propagate up to the head and ruin the tempor.  There is also the issue that unevenly heating most glasses will cause it to shatter long before it melts; so, the video also relies on a relatively modern glass to make this possible.

What is the melting point of Glass?
Approximately 1,400 to 1,600 degrees Celsius (C) or 2,552 to 1,912 degrees Fahrenheit (F).
What are the melting points of various metals known in ancient times.
Cast Iron: 1204°C (2200°F)
Copper: 1084°C (1983°F)
Gold: 1063°C (1945°F)
Silver: 961°C (1762°F)
Bronze: 950 °C (1,742°F)
Brass: 930°C (1710°F)
Zinc: 420°C (787°F)
Lead: 328°C (622°F)
Tin: about 232 °C (450 °F)
Mercury: -38.83 ?C (-37.894 F)
So if Prince Rupert's drops have the same melting point as most forms of glass, a piece of metal could be melted at a temperatue lower than the melting point of glass, and then Prince Rupert's drops inserted onto the surface of the metal a sufficient distance.  When the metal cools the Prince Rupert's drops will be stuck on the surface of the metal if they are inserted deep enough.
So the metal should be made in the right size and shape for pieces of scale armor and then melted and the Prince Rupert's drops inserted, and then cooled until it is solid.  And then the scales can be attached to the the underlying surface of the armor.
So what the Prince Rupert's drops covered metal scales would look like would depend on what metals were used for the scales and how transparent or reflective the Prince Rupert's drops would be.
I suggest the armor scales should be made of iron, steel, or bronze underneath with the scales of gold, silver, brass, or other bright metal covered in Prince Rupert's trops attached on top.

It might be difficult to work-harden the scales once the glass has been set in them (though I believe the question didn't mind the armour being purely ornamental and not actually functional) but perhaps the drops could be added with a more traditional crown by a jeweler after the armour is finished? Then you could get the PRDs in and still have functional armour...

Placing glass, especially a stress tempered glass into a molten metal will make them explode.  You'd  need to in-set them

Borosilicate glass may need that kind of temperatures, but a lot of glassworking is done at a temperature closer to 800C.

In the absence of contradictory statements in your post above?
In your question above Prince Rupert's Drops are (as has been stated previously in one other answer) a form of toughened glass. These 'drops' are not scale shaped as per your picture, they're basically spherical with a tail attached.  And while the 'sphere is 'tough' the tail is not!
So your basic problem is that unlike the scale armor shown in your photo there's no way to secure them to the underlying cloth/leather base. Scale armor has holes drilled/pierced into each scale through which scales can be attached to that base. You don't see these because the scales overlay each other in a pattern deliberately designed to cover these weak points in the armor.
So to answer your question in order to attach each individual drop you to the backing only have two choices:
A) Leave the 'tails' on each drop and sew the drops onto the base using the thin tails as the point to which you wrap around your thread/tie.
B) Ignore the tails (leave them on or cut them off but instead drill through the toughened glass beads themselves to make a hole through which you can secure them to the base.
Both are BAD options. With option A? The first strike will shatter the tails and cause the beads to fall off and roll around on the floor like pearls off broken necklace. And every strike after that? The same thing will happen.
With option B? Even if you can succeed in drilling the necessary hole in any one bead without destroying it? Those that do survive without shattering? You'll have destroyed the exact physical properties that made the beads so tough and desirable in the first place. Result? When struck most of the beads will tend to shatter and/or repeat the same behavior as per option A depending upon how the beads are threaded onto the base because the thread remains the weak point and any strike that doesn't shatter a bead? Will tend to be deflected by an edged weapon down into the gap between each spherical bead.
Stick to steel, bronze, or titanium etc etc.

Actually Option A is even worse than this.  There are high tension striations in the glass that connect the tail to the head.  If you damage the tail, the head also shatters.

The question mentions that you can melt off the tail and leave you a drop without a weak spot.

@toolforger Technically, the question says that they "know that melting the tail off one removes its vulnerability", but since you are limited to 16th century tech, they can not actually do that in a way that preserves the bead's tempor.

@toolforger. The problem I was addressing isn't the weak spot left if you cut off the tail. Even assuming a week spot doesn't exist after the tail is removed the problem remains attaching each bead to the underlay. The tails are brittle so they'll shatter if struck which rules them out as an effective attachment point. That leaves the beads themselves. And as I said previously to attach them to the underpay? You need to drill a hole though each bead - which by default also weakens them.

Cutting off the tail of a Prince Rupert's Drop will shatter it, as will drilling a hole into it.

@toolmaker. That was my point! Even assuming that cutting/meting the tail off didn't somehow magically ruin the bead? Doing so and then having to drill or melt a hole in it to attach it to the underplay would. Ergo there's no practical way I can think of making a scale mail armor from it. Laying them in rows on some kind of padded cloth base and then tightly stitching an outer layer of leather/fabric over the top might (I suppose) but that's not the type of armor the poster wants. That would be more like a brigandine. I still don't know how effective it would be as a form of protection though

Since what gives the PRD it's toughness is basically shape, you'd have very hard time using them for armoring. There are several reasons, none related to manufacturing.

you'd need the actual Drops, not the toughened glass (PRDs are essentially toughened/tempered glass, that's in broad use nowadays, but with extra twist),
so they need to stay in the shape of the drop, of course with the tail removed by melting it (as specified),
and you can't apply any kind of mounting aids (i.e. holes or steel rings).

Which means that you'd have to fasten them to the base using thin wire or thread, which basically defeats the purpose of the armor.
However, if this is just ceremonial piece, those limitations can be acceptable. Since glass is about 3 times lighter than steel, you'd get away with it in terms of the total weight of the armor, as this would be at most same weight of the steel one.
Glassmaking took off after discovering blowing (which took place in 1BC in Jerusalem, according to scientific research), so in 1000 AD making glass beads would be, most probably, cheaper than steel plates, as it was established and common industry across Europe.
The only problem I see is the actual PRD discovery happened sometime in the early 17th century AD.
So, bottom line is that I can definitely see a ceremonial armor made with PRD. There were ceremonial armors made from stranger materials.
